# How to advance Physics?

Tags: soft-question, self-learning, mathematical-physics

I am currently in high school and I am an avid lover of Maths and Physics, I am currently doing my GCSE's and (without sounding arrogant) I don't really enjoy how basic our Physics is, I used to have this problem with Maths too until I picked up a (text)book on Linear Algebra (Linear Algebra: A Modern Introduction) which I'm enjoying very much. The issue is, I don't really know where to start: I am reading books on Physics like "QED by Richard Feynman" which I am really enjoying but I don't feel it's enough. I want to advance my Physics and I want to start applying Maths to Physics (why I posted on *Maths.Exchange*), I want to be able to pick up more challenging books on this topic and fully understand them. Yet I also really enjoy the "Physics-Physics side of Physics", I find it very interesting and I am wondering: how can I learn more about Physics (both Mathematically and Theoretically). Through experience I have seemed to grow a higher appreciation for learning stuff through books rather than online, so are there any recommendations of books I can pick up? (I mean as in textbooks, or something which I can study from rather than normal books- those which I am already reading). I know Physics is a very vague name for all the fascinating branches there are, but I would be content with anything - personally, I am really into Astrophysics, but I find everything interesting.

Nevertheless, thank you.

Comment: Why don't you just get a physics textbook and start from there.

Comment: That's the question, I don't know which one to get, I've been searching the whole day, yet I don't know which topic to do. I want it to be much harder than what we do in high-school but I want it to be understandable at my level so I can actually develop myself.

Comment: I highly recommend reading [Teach Yourself Physics: A Travel Companion](https://www.amazon.com/Teach-Yourself-Physics-travel-companion-ebook/dp/B084RSFZLX) as your starting point. It's a great book and gives you a good overview and guide going forward. The Feynman Lectures on Physics are also great, of course. The textbooks by Griffiths are great. And I recommend [Relativity Visualized](https://www.amazon.com/Relativity-Visualized-Lewis-Carroll-Epstein/dp/093521805X) by Epstein as a gentle introduction to special relativity.

Comment: OP what sort of mathematics are you comfortable with? Obviously 'hard' is a relative term, but if you want to do physics that is 'much harder' and at a very high level, you need to be comfortable with the mathematics presented.

Comment: One approach to this problem is to figure out what parts of physics you are most interested in, to narrow down the search.  But if you are just looking for a recommendation of an undergraduate-level physics textbook that is just so good that you have to read it, then I have one recommendation: David Griffiths's *Introduction to Electrodynamics*.  Electromagnetism is a really good bridge between high school physics and high-level physics such as quantum mechanics.  The book is *extremely* readable, and the exercises are really well-chosen as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the advice you will find here may be too situation independent for you as contributors here are from many different places(for those reading, GCSE is equivalent to precalc). Undergraduate textbooks are great, but you will have plenty of time to work through them at university. Shoot for the hoops first by doing well in the exams and getting into a good university.

I would recommend you start looking at A level maths/physics/further maths stuff. Not only will it be fun, you'll be ahead next year too. The Edexcel textbooks are great. Further mechanics modules FM1 and FM2 are more or less exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your point! (I just want to apologize if I sound arrogant in here, that was not at all my intention) I fully understand what you mean, but currently, I don't really care about exams. I have my GCSE's in 2022, which I do care about, but studying Maths and Physics in my spare time has nothing to do with me wanting to do better in my exams, I'm just really enjoying them. When the time comes for me to study, I don't mind doing it, but this is nothing different than people playing video games in their spare time, I just do it because it's fun and I really want to know more about this.

Comment: Yet I still fully appreciate your kind-hearted response and I will definitely look into the Further Mechanics books (did you mean the ones by Brian Jefferson?) which from what I have seen through google previews have a lot of content which I have and haven't seen before and seem very interesting, so thank you a lot! (+1).

Comment: After I finish my Linear Algebra, I also plan to do Calculus (one way or another, as I suspect will be harder but I am still up for it, taking "Calculus" by Spivak), which I really want to do as it seems really interesting and will enable me to start reading books by David Griffiths which was suggested by me on the comments of my post by "sasquires".

Answer (score 1):

For studying astrophysics, I would recommend using the textbook "Relativity: Special, General, and Cosmological" by Wolfgang Rindler to learn more about relativity and "Black Holes, White Dwarfs, and Neutron Stars" by Shapiro and Teukolsky to learn more about the current understanding of some of the most interesting stellar objects. However, a warning: both of these are more graduate level textbooks than for the undergraduate.